# E: Unable to locate package while running apt-get remove

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

I have ubuntu 12.04 lts and when I type:

```
sudo apt-get remove "gPDFText ebook editor"
```

it says:

```
E: Unable to locate package gPDFText ebook editor
```

what should I do?!!

Answer (score 3):

Type

`sudo apt-get remove gpdftext` to remove gPDFText ebook editor.

Comment: it says:
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Make sure you are not running `synaptic`  or any package manageet tool from other terminal. If yes, close it and try again. If not then  you can delete the lock file using folloing command: `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`. You may need to delete lock file from cache directory. Type : `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`.

Comment: Still saying the same

Comment: Reboot and try again.

Comment: it still says the same thing

Comment: I think some other process is using apt. Find it out using command `ps aux | grep apt | grep -v 'grep'`. If any process is using it let it finish or kill it using the command `sudo kill <pid of process >` .pid of process is second column of previous command.